How to iterate over the file and directories of the given path and no need to include sub_directories in zig
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const path = ".";
    const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;

    var dir = try std.fs.cwd().openDir(path, .{ .iterate = true });
    defer dir.close();

    var walker = try dir.walk(allocator);

    defer walker.deinit();

    std.debug.print("\n", .{});
    while (try walker.next()) |entry| {
        std.debug.print("File Name: {s}\n", .{entry.basename});
    }
}

I tried above code which iterate over all current and sub_directories but I don't want sub-directory iteration.
I am trying below approach and if I don't pass .iterate = true I can't iterate only. How to achieve this?

you would pass the .access_sub_paths option as false (docs);
var dir = try std.fs.cwd().openDir(
    path,
    .{
        .access_sub_paths = false, // default is true
        .iterate = true,
    },
);


You could do so like this.
var iterable_dir = std.fs.cwd().openDir(path, .{
    .iterate = true
}) catch @panic("failed to open dir");
defer iterable_dir.close();

var it = iterable_dir.iterate();
while (try it.next()) |entry| {
    if (entry.kind == .file and entry.kind != .directory) {
        std.debug.print("File Name: {s}\n", .{entry.name});
    }
}

